# Get some space on image link

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I get some spaces on tag a

```
<div id="language">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/xbv9ppqhj/language1.png" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/q9xc3imvr/language2.png" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#">lol</a>
</div>

#language a
{
    padding: 0 2px;
    height:21px;
}
#language a img
{   
    line-height:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yokosatan/zcw7u/

How I get the space out of?

Edit: found the similar question and try adding

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

It's work but how the space come? I try line-height and it not work

Latest update

http://jsfiddle.net/yokosatan/zcw7u/1/

Answer (score 0):

you are giving a padding value to your a tag so it's having a space and even if you remove this padding values you can see some space. For this you could give styling `float:left;` to your a tag.

```
#language a
{
    paddi/ng: 0 2px;
    height:21px;
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zcw7u/2/)

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it...if ever you want to make it more closer to each other...

```
#language a
{
    padding: 0 2px;
    height:21px;
    margin-left:-6px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yokosatan/zcw7u/1/